# Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, atomic, compiler-optimization

Will the two loads be combined to one in such scenarios?
If this is architecture dependent, what would be the case in say modern processors from say Intel? I believe atomic loads are equivalent to normal loads in Intel processors.

```
void run1() {
    auto a = atomic_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    auto b = atomic_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
   // Some code using a and b;
}

void run2() {
    if (atomic_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 2 && /*some conditions*/ ...) {
         if (atomic_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) * somevar > 3) {
               /*...*/
         }
    }
}
```

`run1()` and `run2()` are simply two scenarios using two loads of the same atomic variable. Can the compiler collapse such scenarios of two loads into one load and reuse that?

Comment: Sorry, why do you have both `run1` and `run2`? Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: @Brian Simply two scenarios. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Can the compiler optimize away atomic loads?

Your implementation of `run1()` can be safely optimized to

```
void run1() {
    auto a = atomic_var.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    auto b = a;
   // Some code using a and b;
}
```

In the original program the two loads could possibly be adjacent to each other in the total order of accesses on `atomic_var` every time `run1()` is called. In that case the adjacent `load()` operations would return the same result.

Since that possibility cannot be excluded, the compiler is allowed to optimize away the second `load()`. This can be done for any memory order argument, not just for relaxed atomics.

For `run2()` it depends. You didn't specify `/*some conditions*/`. If there's something, that might have a visible side effect on the atomic variable (like an opaque function call or accessing a volatile variable, etc.) then this cannot be optimized away. Otherwise it might be possible.

### Does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?

Depends on your compiler. And possibly on the compiler options you passed in. Possibly it depends on your platform. There is some debate going on, on whether compilers should optimize atomics. There is [N4455 No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html#n4455-no-sane-compiler-would-optimize-atomics) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB57wIf9W1k) as a start on the topic.

GCC and clang don't optimize the two `load()` operations onto one at the moment.

Comment: So, the answer as of now is the standard allows, but the modern compilers don't do it and it is still a subject of discussion.

Comment: That's probably correct. At least in this case they don't optimize (much). Maybe they do in other cases. Surely, modern optimizing compilers perform reorderings of stores and loads around atomics as far as their memory orderings permit it. For a C++ programmer the C++ standard is the interface to code against. Relying on whether the compiler optimizes something or not is usually not a good idea, since bugs can be introduced with any new compiler update otherwise.

Comment: A recent question asked the same thing about coalescing repeated stores.  My answer there is essentially the same as your answer here, including linking N4455 (but also http://wg21.link/p0062).  Also some stuff about *why* compilers choose not to, until this is sorted out.

Comment: Anyway, so I closed this as a duplicate of the new one.

Comment: "_There is some debate going on, on whether compilers should optimize atomics_" but there is no debate that the optimization is valid in such simple case

Answer (score 4):

Neither GCC (6.3) nor Clang (3.9) currently optimizes the two loads into one.

The only way to know is to look at the generated assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/nZ3Ekm

Comment: Is it allowed by the standard? Doesn't volatile say that you need to load everytime? Why does that count for atomic.

Comment: @themagicalyang: `std::atomic` does not have to use `volatile`, and  it should be possible to combine the two loads under `memory_order_relaxed`.  You could file a report about this on GCC's bug tracker and see what they say.  Be sure to link to it here if you do!

Comment: @themagicalyang: If you want a `volatile std::atomic<int>` , then use that. But you left out the definition of `atomic_var` so we have no reason to assume it's `volatile`.

Comment: Lots of information on this can be found on JF Bastien's excellent post: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html