# C/C++: relaxed std::atomic<bool> vs unlocked bool on X64 architecture

Tags: c++, performance, synchronization, x86-64, atomic

Is there any efficency benefit to using an unlocked boolean over using an `std::atomic<bool>` where the operations are always done with relaxed memory order? I would assume that both eventually compile to the same machine code, since a single byte is actually atomic on X64 hardware. Am I wrong?

Comment: "since a single byte is actually atomic in hardware" - that's not a given fact.

Comment: Not even on X64 architecture? (Note what I wrote in the title)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I doubt there are any architectures where a byte load or store isn't atomic.  (Except rare ISAs like early DEC Alpha that don't *have* byte load/store instructions, only word.  Or word-addressable DSPs.  But on them, `bool` would be a word wide, not a byte.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's are potentially massive advantages, especially for local variables, or any variable used repeatedly in the same function.  **An `atomic<>` variable can't be optimized into a register.**

**If you compiled without optimization, the code-gen would be similar, but compiling with normal optimization enabled there can be massive differences.**  Un-optimized code is similar to making every variable `volatile`.

---

Current compilers also never combine multiple reads of an `atomic` variable into one, as if you'd used `volatile atomic<T>`, because that's what people expect and the dust hasn't settled yet on how to allow useful optimizations while prohibiting ones you *don't* want.  ([Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960387/why-dont-compilers-merge-redundant-stdatomic-writes) and [Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820539/can-and-does-the-compiler-optimize-out-two-atomic-loads)).

This isn't a great example, but imagine that checking the boolean is done inside an inlined function, and that there's something else inside the loop.  (Otherwise you'd put the `if` around the loop like a normal person.)

```
int sumarr_atomic(int arr[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++) {
        if (atomic_bool.load (std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

[See the asm output on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z: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%2BUWqmt/bVE1E80dLpmABuqDw6HWqAADjs8f6poHkezQ7z2RHuTzknzYzwy5TtZK4qn1OjjLXaFr9b2geezFJCoxpOipKQWNITA/UNJNPzeJDROJMErZLQD4EM%2B143gA1iA6ImEsAAcXBcDBAAsABsJglAAnLIMEmIh6K3lIiEPk%2BUgvqQb5SA%2BgggCYpDASR16kHAsBIGguhjngDCFuQlCsexnHECAwBwaQEwcQQhZURArggaQrgKI0zzSIBpCsQ8dIAPIsAwin0aQWAwmwnEyfgUTIAQeD9mMMmYL8yAiOJSkPuCmAMDJBDEHguiOTezBsCgn4CAweCuFRkA3uO5moCwVFSAAtOpsiUT%2BEh0D5d5ETJ5HfDByGxchiGqMAyDODBSxcNcuCENMcj0KomiOHxhb/rQxQfhuQEgaWpAQYh6FLLQJQlLQ6KyOhXAmMhtDoeiKH4YRj6ZdIlHUbRnVpVIXAZbp5EdfRXWWcQgh4FFICIUAA%3D%3D).

But with a non-atomic `bool`, the compiler can make that transformation for you by hoisting the load, and then auto-vectorize the simple sum loop (or not run it at all).

With `atomic_bool`, it can't.  With atomic_bool, the asm loop is much like the C++ source, actually doing a test and branch on the value of the variable inside every loop iteration.  And this of course defeats auto-vectorization.

(The C++ as-if rules would allow the compiler to hoist the load because it's relaxed so it can reorder with non-atomic accesses.  And merge because reading the same value every time is one possible result of a global order that reads one value.  But as I said, compilers don't do that.)

---

Loops over an array of `bool` can auto-vectorize, but not over `atomic<bool> []`.

---

Also, inverting a boolean with something like `b ^= 1;` or `b++` can be just a regular RMW, not atomic RMW, so it doesn't have to use `lock xor` or `lock btc`.  (x86 atomic RMW is only possible with sequential-consistency vs. runtime reordering, i.e. the `lock` prefix is also a full memory barrier.)

Code that modifies a non-atomic boolean can optimize away the actual modifications, e.g.

```
void loop() {
    for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++) {
        regular_bool ^= 1;
    }
}
```

compiles to asm that keeps `regular_bool` in a register.  Unfortunately it doesn't optimize away to nothing (which it could because flipping a boolean an even number of times sets it back to its original value).  But it could with a smarter compiler.

```
loop():
    movzx   edx, BYTE PTR regular_bool[rip]   # load into a register
    mov     eax, 10000
.L17:                     # do {
    xor     edx, 1          # flip the boolean
    sub     eax, 1
    jne     .L17          # } while(--i);
    mov     BYTE PTR regular_bool[rip], dl    # store back the result
    ret
```

Even if written as `atomic_b.store( !atomic_b.load(mo_relaxed),  mo_relaxed)` (separate atomic loads/stores), you'd still get a store/reload in the loop, creating a 6-cycle loop-carried dependency chain through the store/reload (on Intel CPUs with 5-cycle store-forwarding latency) instead of a 1-cycle dep chain through a register.

Answer (score 2):

Checking over at [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/0Y0d7y), loading a regular `bool` and a `std::atomic<bool>` generate different code, although not because of synchronisation issues.  Instead, the compiler (gcc) seems unwilling to assume that a `std::atomic<bool>` is guaranteed to be either 0 or 1.  Strange, that.

Clang does the same thing, although the code generated is slightly different in detail.

Comment: Using `cout <<` clutters the code a lot.  https://godbolt.org/z/hFEQ5f is easier to read with separate functions that return the value of the global, like  `bool load_regular() {
    return regular_bool;
}` that compiles to a single movzx.  (And the atomic version still booleanizes for no apparent reason.)

Comment: @Peter I did it that way to stop the compiler optimising out the loads.  Although I see from your example that moving the load into a separate function generates better code.

Comment: Yeah I know, and my point is that returning a value from a function instead of writing a `main` solves the same problem much more cleanly.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  Remember you're just writing code so you can look at the asm, not run it.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I see you never bother to call the functions so that gcc cannot inline them or optimise them away.  A useful trick that.

Comment: Even if you did write callers, you can still look at the stand-alone definition *as well*, if you don't make them `static` or `inline`.