# Why do GCC inserts mfence where Clang dont use it?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang, atomic

Why do GCC and Clang generates so different asm for this code (x86_64, -O3 -std=c++17)?

```
#include <atomic>

int global_var = 0;

int foo_seq_cst(int a)
{
    std::atomic<int> ia;
    ia.store(global_var + a, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    return ia.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}

int foo_relaxed(int a)
{
    std::atomic<int> ia;
    ia.store(global_var + a, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return ia.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

GCC 9.1:

```
foo_seq_cst(int):
        add     edi, DWORD PTR global_var[rip]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], edi
        mfence
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        ret
foo_relaxed(int):
        add     edi, DWORD PTR global_var[rip]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        ret
```

Clang 8.0:

```
foo_seq_cst(int):                       # @foo_seq_cst(int)
        mov     eax, edi
        add     eax, dword ptr [rip + global_var]
        ret
foo_relaxed(int):                       # @foo_relaxed(int)
        mov     eax, edi
        add     eax, dword ptr [rip + global_var]
        ret
```

I suspect that mfence here is an overkill, am I right? Or Clang generates code that can leads to bugs in some cases?

Comment: godbolt comparison https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GFCEY3

Comment: It would seem that since the atomic is a local variable, clang recognizes that only one thread has access to it and avoids generating code for the atomic at all.

Comment: So GCC do not optimize well and mfence can be thrown away?

Comment: Yes, if you're like here the single thread working with a variable, there is no need for an mfence. If you force clang to generate code for the variable anyway, it will correctly use a memory fence ("built into" the xchg instruction) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_-XLEs

Comment: GCC doesn't get atomics at the core language level, they are treated as library function calls, think `printf`, never removed. Clang generates expected code.

Comment: [tag:multithreading] doesn't seem relevant as there is only one thread of execution, the thread of execution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56046501/963864

Comment: Clang still optimizes [very poorly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YaUuJf) redundant writes: `mov     dword ptr [rip + ia], edi ; xchg    dword ptr [rip + ia], edi`

Comment: Maybe if you could explain why you would want a meaningless pseudo release operation to produce a fence we could explain why the intuition is incorrect. Releasing a shooting to the whole world that you have accomplished something and you set a flag to tell that. Who are you shooting at and what flag are you setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more realistic [example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LWrwBV):

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> a;

void foo_seq_cst(int b) {
    a = b;
}

void foo_relaxed(int b) {
    a.store(b, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

gcc-9.1:

```
foo_seq_cst(int):
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], edi
        mfence
        ret
foo_relaxed(int):
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], edi
        ret
```

clang-8.0:

```
foo_seq_cst(int):                       # @foo_seq_cst(int)
        xchg    dword ptr [rip + a], edi
        ret
foo_relaxed(int):                       # @foo_relaxed(int)
        mov     dword ptr [rip + a], edi
        ret
```

gcc uses `mfence`, whereas clang uses `xchg` for `std::memory_order_seq_cst`.

`xchg` implies `lock` prefix. Both `lock` and `mfence` satisfy the requirements of `std::memory_order_seq_cst`, which is no reordering and total order.

From Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual:

> **MFENCE—Memory Fence**
>
> Performs a serializing operation on all load-from-memory and store-to-memory instructions that were issued prior
>   the MFENCE instruction. This serializing operation guarantees that every load and store instruction that precedes
>   the MFENCE instruction in program order becomes globally visible before any load or store instruction that follows
>   the MFENCE instruction. The MFENCE instruction is ordered with respect to all load and store instructions, other
>   MFENCE instructions, any LFENCE and SFENCE instructions, and any serializing instructions (such as the CPUID
>   instruction). MFENCE does not serialize the instruction stream.
>
> 8.2.3.8 **Locked Instructions Have a Total Order**
>
> The memory-ordering model ensures that all processors agree on a single execution order of all locked instructions, including those that are larger than 8 bytes or are not naturally aligned.
>
> 8.2.3.9
>   **Loads and Stores Are Not Reordered with Locked Instructions**
>
> The memory-ordering model prevents loads and stores from being reordered with locked instructions that execute
>   earlier or later.

[`lock` was benchmarked to be 2-3x faster than `mfence`](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20160112150032-mutt-send-email-mst@redhat.com/T/#u) and Linux switched from `mfence` to `lock` where possible.

Comment: Is there an entry in gcc's bugzilla about replacing mfence with lock?