# Fastest way to perform an atomic read in this *very* specific situation?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, clang, atomic

#### Background

It [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56046501/541686) that all(?) compilers treat `std::atomic::load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` as a **volatile** load (via `__iso_volatile_load64`, etc.).
They don't optimize or reorder it at all. Even discarding the loaded value still generates a load instruction, because compilers treat it like it can have side effects.

So, relaxed loads are suboptimal. With that said...

---

#### Question (x86)

Assume `p` points to a **monotonically-increasing 8-byte counter in shared memory** that is **only written to *outside* my process**. My program only reads from this address.

I want to read this counter in a manner such that:

1. Loads are *atomic* (no tearing)
2. Ordering is preserved for *this counter* (so that `x = *p; y = *p;` implies `x <= y`)
3. Loads are **not** treated as opaque/optimization barriers (except for #2 above)

In particular, the intent here is that the compiler performs as many of the optimizations as it can like it would do on normal memory accesses, e.g.: useless loads (like `(void)*p;`) get discarded, *other* instructions get reordered freely around this memory access, etc.

Is there any way to achieve this on either MSVC or Clang other than with volatile loads?

(Implementation-specific hacks/intrinsics/etc. **are OK**, as long as those specific implementations never treat it like undefined behavior, so there is no risk of wrong codegen.)

Comment: Are you ok with loads getting hoisted out of loops, e.g. `for() arr[i] = *p;` turns into `auto tmp = *p;` / `std::fill(arr, arr+len, tmp)`?  Or does your code not do anything like that, so even after inlining, function boundaries are enough to constrain things to read often enough?  (Not that I know of anything that could do that other than just making it non-atomic, which would be too weak wrt. read-read coherence (your point 2).  One mechanism for such reordering is a compiler re-reading `*p` where the source reads `x` - see https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ compilers *can* invent loads.)

Comment: Likewise, your criteria would seem to allow `while (*p < stop_val) { compute(); }` to be transformed into `if (*p < stop_val) { while (1) { compute(); } }`.  Are you sure that's okay?  For that matter, if `compute()` has no side effects visible to other threads avoiding data races, then it's UB to execute it in an infinite loop, so the compiler could also give you `if (*p < stop_val) { nasal_demons(); }`.

Comment: I posted an answer on [Why are unnecessary atomic loads not optimized away?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56046501) - I'm not 100% sure that optimizing away unused `relaxed` loads is always safe, since `thread_fence(acquire)` in a caller could create a happens-before relationship with another thread.   There are still optimizations that would be perfectly valid both on paper and in practice, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: *"Are you ok with loads getting hoisted out of loops?"* yup I'm fine with - in fact, even without that, it's still possible for the code to see the same values (there's no guarantee of counter progress), so my code wouldn't know the difference. Regarding your other answer, interesting point about `atomic_thread_fence` - thanks!

Comment: @NateEldredge: In my case the counter is guaranteed to *eventually* change regardless of the loop, so I want the compiler to understand that. i.e. it shouldn't turn that loop into UB, because it's guaranteed not to be infinite. I guess you can think of it as still being "volatile" in the sense that it can change from outside the program. It's just not volatile in the sense of its reads having side effects.

Comment: To clarify what may look like a contradiction above: there's no guarantee of counter progress in *finite* time (hence why it's OK for the `for` loop to have it hoisted out). But it's guaranteed to progress *eventually*.

Comment: Ok.  The semantics you're looking for are exactly what ISO C++ guarantees for `std::atomic` `.load(relaxed)`.  No real-world compilers are anywhere near that weak in terms of optimizing atomics, and it's unlikely that they'll change in ways that let existing code optimize that much, but I'm pretty sure there's no middle ground that compilers understand as a being allowed to CSE except when that would create infinite loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`const std::atomic<uint64_t> *p` or `std::atomic_ref<>` with `std::memory_order_relaxed` give you most of what you want, except for [common-subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (CSE).  In future compilers, you might even get a limited amount of that, or at least optimizing away unused loads.  ISO C++ on paper guarantees just barely enough for your use case.

**I don't know of anything that's weaker than that but still safe.** Making it plain (non-atomic/non-volatile) and wouldn't give you read-read coherence. Even if you write`int x = *p;` in the source, some (maybe not all) later uses of `x` might actually reload from `*p`.   See the "invented loads" section of [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/#Invented%20Loads) on LWN.  This might happen for some later uses of `x` but not all, making the variable change value.  Or for `x` but not `y`, allowing violation of `x<=y`.

Perhaps you use GNU C inline asm like `int x = *p; asm("" ::: "memory");` to tell the compiler `*p` might have changed. Or maybe a less optimization-hurting thing like `asm("" : "+g"(*p))` to tell it only to forget about the value of `*p` without being a compiler barrier to all memory reordering.  But that's still going to prevent CSE of multiple loads since you're still manually telling the compiler where to forget about things.

Plus, it's hypothetically possible that it might do `x = *p` non-atomically if it's not `volatile` or `atomic`, depending on surrounding code; *[Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71866535/which-types-on-a-64-bit-computer-are-naturally-atomic-in-gnu-c-and-gnu-c-m)* shows an example of a 64-bit store on AArch64 that GCC chooses to compile with `stp` of the same value for both halves of the pair, which isn't guaranteed atomic until ARMv8.4 or something.  So using non-atomic types and relying on memory barriers is the worst of both worlds, and *not* guaranteed to work by any compiler-specific guarantees; it is still data-race UB in MSVC and GNU C++

---

#### `std::atomic<>` with `relaxed` meets your correctness requirements

1. Lock-free `std::atomic` loads always compile to something that's atomic in hardware, and `atomic<uint64_t>` should be lock-free on all mainstream x86 compilers even in 32-bit mode.  (Not 100% sure about MSVC, but GCC and Clang know how to use SSE2 `movq` for 8-byte atomic loads in 32-bit mode.)
2. Even `relaxed` atomics have read-read coherence ([[intro.races]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19)): subsequent reads will see the same or a later value in the modification-order.  This prevents compile-time reordering, and coherent caches + hardware guarantees make this happen for free (without any extra barrier instructions) even on non-x86 ISAs.
3. Compilers can and do reorder other memory ops on other vars around `relaxed` atomic load/store.

   Same goes for `volatile` with GCC/clang (and MSVC with `/volatile:iso` to make sure it's not treating it as `acquire`/`release` even when compiling for x86).  But `std::atomic` with `relaxed` portably expresses exactly the semantics you want so future compilers might optimize better.  And `volatile` ops can't reorder at compile time with other `volatile` ops regardless of which location, unlike atomic `relaxed` which can.

---

`std::atomic` loads even on non-x86 are just plain asm loads, at least for types that fit in a single register like `uint64_t` on x86-64.

Current GCC and Clang do have some minor missed optimizations, though, like they won't use a `std::atomic<>.load` as a memory source operand for another instruction (https://godbolt.org/z/sf8WcG7qs)

```
#include <atomic>

using T = std::atomic<long>;
long read(T &a, long dummy){
    return dummy + a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + a.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
```

```
# GCC13.2 -O3 ;  clang is equivalent
read(std::atomic<long long>&, long):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     rax, rsi
        add     rax, rdx
        ret
```

vs.

```
long read_plain(long *p, long *q, long dummy){
    return dummy + *p + *q;
}
```

```
## GCC13 -O3  ; clang is similar
read_plain(long*, long*, long):
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        add     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]   ### memory source operand
        add     rax, rdx
        ret
```

It would be nice if they fixed stuff like that; there's no reason `a.store(1 + a.load(relaxed), relaxed);` shouldn't compile to `add qword ptr [rdi], 1` (without `lock` since I didn't use `a.fetch_add`), but GCC will do a separate load / inc / store, like with `volatile` but unlike with plain `long`.

Clang actually *will* use `inc qword ptr [rdi]` for that atomic load/add/store, so it's only GCC and MSVC with missed optimizations in that case.

Clang will also use `volatile` loads as memory source operands for `add`, like

```
long read_volatile(volatile long *p, volatile long *q, long dummy){
    return dummy + *p + *q;
}
```

```
# clang 17 -O3
read_volatile(long volatile*, long volatile*, long):
        mov     rax, rdx
        add     rax, qword ptr [rdi]  # same asm it makes for non-volatile
        add     rax, qword ptr [rsi]  # unlike GCC which makes asm like for atomic
        ret
```

And yes, this asm is arguably worse than GCC's plain case: on CPUs without mov-elimination, it's more back-end uops (2 each from `add`, plus one from the `mov` if not eliminated), and the `mov` would be on the critical path for latency from `dummy` to result.  But that choice is unrelated to `volatile` vs. `atomic`.

So you might consider using `volatile` for now, especially if you're using Clang, since you're compiling for a CISC ISA (x86) where folding loads into memory source operands for other instruction saves front-end bandwidth.

Comment: +1 thanks for the discussion. The point about invented loads and read-read coherence is a really great one. Any idea if it can be avoided by marking the locally copied variable as volatile?

Comment: @user541686: Like `volatile int tmpx = *p;` `int tmp = tmpx;`?   Yeah, that would prevent the compiler from replacing later uses of `tmp` with the original `*p` shared data. (I copied it back to a non-volatile local to avoid destroying optimization of repeated use of it.) Or in GNU C++ `int tmp = *p;  asm("" : "+r"(tmp));` telling the compiler that `tmp = black_box(tmp);` and the value has to be in a register.  The black box is zero asm instructions; an empty asm template.  `Benchmark::DoNotOptimize` is a similar idea, but includes "memory" clobber and might only read, I forget.