# std::atomic address after store

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17, language-lawyer, stdatomic

I can't seem to get the address of an atomic object after a store.

e.g.

```
std::atomic<int> i;
std::atomic<int>* p = &++i; // doesn't work
auto* p = &++i; // doesn't work
// below works:
++i;
auto* p = &i;
```

What's happening here and why?

To clarify: I know it returns an r-value. Why doesn't it return the original object, `this`? Is this a purposeful design choice or was it an oversight?

More specifically, what's happening under-the-hood for this requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the pre-increment operator *usually* returns its operand by reference, in the case of `std::atomic` integers, it returns the new value as a temporary. So in your example `++i` does not return a reference to the `atomic<int> i` itself, it returns the new value of `i` (i.e. an int). You can see this at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith

It would be misleading and even dangerous to return a reference to the original `atomic<int>`, because to access the int value through this reference would require a **second, separate read operation** — so its value might be different from the value at the time of increment. (This isn't particularly relevant your example code, since you are only trying to obtain a pointer to the referenced object, but some code will actually access the value after `++` so this is why returning a reference isn't possible.)

In other words, if `++i` returned a reference to the `atomic<int> i`, then

```cpp
int j = ++i;
```

would be equivalent to

```cpp
++i;
// ...other threads may modify the value of `i` here!...
int j = i;
```

The whole point of atomics is to perform reads and writes together as an indivisible operation, so `++i` must internally use hardware/OS atomic operations to simultaneously read and increment the integer, so the new value is returned as a temporary.

If you're curious to see what's under the hood, [here is libc++'s implementation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6a64079699e7b56badd292e39cad4b8bfe941aec/libcxx/include/atomic#L1741-L1744) where you can see that `operator++` simply calls into `fetch_add(1)` and returns the result + 1.

Comment: Seems kind of stupid. Why not just make a lazy-eval type that can do both? This way there's no unnecessary load so that you may do stuff like `++i` without the fetch, and also can still do the fetch immediately without any desync issues.

Comment: That might be technically possible, but I don't think it would really lead to safer, more readable code; rather it would make it easier to get things subtly wrong (and complicating the library at that).

Comment: C++ STL has no responsibility to ensure things aren't "subtly wrong". There's plenty of things you can do to misuse the library already, what's one more? Especially since it's possibly 10 lines of code that leads to theoretically *faster* codegen.

Comment: @lajoh90686: Because optimizing atomics is a hard problem that language standards + compilers haven't solved yet.  [Can and does the compiler optimize out two atomic loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41820539).  In this case, what would the advantage be?  For it to be usable, you'd need a *guarantee* that you got the same value that `++i` stored, not just the *option* for the compiler to optimize that way, so it makes vastly more sense to return a `T` by value instead of an `atomic<T>` reference.

Comment: At any rate, I think the practice of providing atomic `fetch_add` instructions goes all the way to hardware, which is to say I'm not aware of (and with a quick search can't find any) operations of the form "increment atomically but *don't* return any value". Given that's how it works in hardware there's not really an extra cost to this design.

Comment: @jtbandes: Note that the problem isn't that the subsequent load wouldn't be "synchronized".  It's on the same object in the same thread, so the RMW "happens before" the load from anything that would reference the hypothetical return-by-reference object.  The problem is that it defeats the atomicity, letting that later load possibly depend on something another thread did, separate from the `++` this thread did.

Comment: That's what I meant to convey but I clearly didn't use sufficiently precise terminology; my apologies :)

Comment: IMO it's an important concept that barriers / ordering don't create atomicity.  And that atomic RMW with `mo_relaxed` can still be atomic, just not ordered wrt. other modifications.  (Defining `++` in terms of `fetch_add` is another reason it needs to return a `T` value; `fetch_add` clearly needs to return the value, not a reference.)

Comment: re: hardware increment without returning the value: x86 can do this: `lock add dword [mem], 1` doesn't put the old or new value in a register, only updates FLAGS based on it.  If you want the actual value, you need `lock xadd [mem], eax` to exchange-and-add.  Or for operations other than +-, you need a CAS loop if you use the result of `atomic |= 1` or something.  There's no asm equivalent for `fetch_or`, only atomic `lock or [mem], reg` or immediate.  related: [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850).

Comment: LL/SC machines always need retry loops and always have the old and new values in registers that you can leave around for later, but ISAs like x86 that can make a memory-destination instruction atomic need special instructions to also put the memory value into a register like `fetch_*`

Comment: Of course, when you *don't* use the return value, good compilers *do* optimize to `lock or` or whatever.  https://godbolt.org/z/MKvzcc.

Comment: *The whole point of atomics is to perform reads and writes together as an indivisible operation* - not quite correct.  Another important use-case is pure-load and pure-store operations.  Some algorithms don't need any RMWs on one object, but do need loads and stores to it to be atomic (no tearing) and often also ordered.  And at a C++ level, free from UB, so rolling your own with `volatile` is almost always a bad idea.  (And of course using just plain variables is totally broken in practice by common optimizations like keeping a value in a register, which assumption of no data-race UB allows)